# How to change the text on active state jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've this lil piece of code, I have done what I wanted, just one thing is that am not able to chane the word when the div is expanded, I want to make text `Less -` and when is it not expanded `More +`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FXGLH/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var visible=true;
    $("#more_details").on('click', function() { 
    $('.more_details').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
         visible=!visible;    
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var visible=true;
  $("#more_details").on('click', function() { 
    $('.more_details').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
    visible=!visible;
    $(this).text(visible ? 'More +' : 'Less -');
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FXGLH/1/)

Comment: Awesome, +1 anything about the `z-index`?

Comment: What's the problem with z-index?

Comment: You can use .toggle(); for #more_details

Comment: @MateiMihai I am not able to click on less once it's opened, you see your fiddle

Comment: @AcidicCloud: use if statement for check .text()

Comment: @MateiMihai am not able to, am on chrome

Comment: @MateiMihai got it,, ID and class, specificity issues, thanks ;) will accept once system allows me

Comment: `z-index: 2;` makes the `#more_details` item keep on top of the other one with `z-index: 1;`

Comment: @MateiMihai still z-index issue, I tried but no luck, test it on chrome